# Easily Generate Mock HTTP Response for TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am attempting to mock some responses in TestCafe and mocking the responses is pretty slow going. The workflow I would like is something like this:

- Walk through a test scenario in Chrome.
- Copy the selected network request to mock as a curl command.
- Paste it in to a curl command to Testcafe translator.
- Paste it in to testcafe.

I haven't found a good way to generate mock requests other than manually typing them out by hand. Is anyone aware of any tools which allow you to translate a fetch or curl command to TestCafe mock response?

Answer (score 3):

The [RequestMock.onRequestTo](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto.html) method gives an ability to identify and filter requests by their urls or parameters. You can simply copy a request url and response body from the Chrome DevTools Network tab and pass them to the `onRequestTo` and `respond` methods.

Comment: Yes I was asking if there was any tooling that helped do this automatically vs doing it by hand for each request.